# Need my C# JSON.text file to have Default HighScores if it gets deleted or values are changed (UNITY)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, save

How can I add default int and string name values to a JSON.txt though C#?

Answer (score 1):

I would first create the default collection of HighScore with all of those fake players:

```
private List<Score> scores = null;
void Start()
{
    this.scores = new List<Score>()
    {
         new Score("Adam", 10000), new Score("Eve",7500); // ...
    };
    Score[]scores = GetJsonFileWithScore(); // This is where you get the real players score
    this.scores.AddRange(scores);
    this.scores.OrderBy (s => s.score); // Order it by score
    int index = 4;
    this.scores.RemoveRange(index, list.Count - index); // keep only the best 5
}
```